# How to write a javascript programme for following requierement?

Tags: javascript

Create three functions of bank Deposit, Withdraw and Statement
When I pass the amount value in Deposit it add the amount, Withdraw is deduct the
amount and statement shows total remaining amount and last transaction.
If user try to withdraw more than deposit than transaction shouldn’t process and amount
will remain same

i am a newbie in javaScript and below is what i've achieve so far... but is there any other better way to get the solution?

```js
var Balance = 100;
var latestBalance;

function deposite (credited) {
  Balance += credited;

  latestTrans = credited;
  console.log('Balance after Deposite: £', + Balance +'.00');
}

function withdrawal (debited) {
  if (debited > Balance) {
    console.log('user not allowed to withdraw this amount. Please enter lower amount');
  } else {
    Balance -= debited;
    latestTrans = debited;
    console.log('Balance after withdrawal: £', + Balance + '.00');
  }
}

function statement (totalAmt) {
  console.log('Total available balance is: £ '  + Balance +'.00');
  console.log('Latest Transaction is: £ '  + latestTrans +'.00' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to write this code. 
For example it is a common naming convention to save capitalizing the first letter of a variable for constructor functions. 
This solution may be overkill for your assignment however it is a cleaner way to write your code.

```
//create an object to hold the balance of an account and methods to modify only that balance
const Account = function(balance) {
  this.balance = balance;
  this.transactions = []
  this.getBalance = function() {
    return balance
  };
  this.widthdraw = function(amount) {
    if(amount > balance) {
      console.log('You dont have enough money');
      return;
    } else {
      balance -= amount
      this.transactions.push({ widthdraw: amount })
      return balance;
    }
  }
  this.deposit = function(amount) {
    balance += amount
    this.transactions.push({ deposit : amount })
    }
  }

var newAcc = new Account(100)

console.log(newAcc.getBalance())
//output: 100
console.log(newAcc.widthdraw(20))
//output: 80
console.log(newAcc.deposit(50))
//output: 130
console.log(newAcc.transactions[newAcc.transactions.length - 1])
//output: Object: deposit : 50
```

This example is an objectively better way to achieve your goal because the balance is stored in an object and the methods on that object only modify that balance.

The Account function create a new object with which you can easily modify the balance of an account. You can create a new account by using the new keyword and passing in an initial value. 
 
 
 
The transactions array is essentially a cache of all transactions. You can access the last item in that array to find your last transaction. 

 
For further explanation on this example look into scope and closures.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to write any program, not necessarily better or worse.

Here are a few notes however:

- `latestBalance` does nothing
- `latestTrans` is not declared, so if you are in a browser, it will be placed as a property of the `window` object. If on node, then it will be placed in the `global` object. This is generally bad practice.
- `totalAmt` in the `statement` function is not used.
- If we go off your program description, `Withdraw` does not show the latest transaction, so is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to follow [SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles when writing applications and splitting your code into smaller chunks and following design patterns will help your code to be more maintainable, scalable, and performant.

There are many ways to solve problems and different patterns can be followed. Solving this problem OOP-style could look something like:

```
/**
* Public API for the customer
*/
class BankCustomerClient {
    constructor(initialBalance) {
    this.account = new Account(initialBalance, '');
    this.bankOperations = new BankOperations();
  }

  /**
  * @param amount The amount to be despoited into the account
  */
  deposit(amount) {
    this.account.balance = this.bankOperations.performActionWithBalance(BankOperationActions.DEPOSIT, this.account.balance, amount);
    this.account.latestTransaction = '+' + amount.toString();
    ClientLogger.balance(this.account.balance);
  }

  /**
  * @param amount The amount to be withdrawn from the account
  */
  withdraw(amount) {
    if (WithdrawlRules.canWithdraw(amount, this.account.balance)) {
      this.account.balance = this.bankOperations.performActionWithBalance(BankOperationActions.WITHDRAW, this.account.balance, amount);
      this.account.latestTransaction = '-' + amount.toString();
      ClientLogger.balance(this.account.balance);
    } else {
        ClientLogger.notAllowedToWithdraw();
    }
  }

  /**
  * Logs a statement
  */
  statement() {
    ClientLogger.balance(this.account.balance);
    ClientLogger.latestTransation(this.account.latestTransaction);
  }
}

/**
* Hold account information
*/
class Account {
    constructor(balance, latestTransaction) {
    this.balance = balance;
    this.latestTransaction = latestTransaction;
  }
}

/**
* Logger class for the bank client
*/
class ClientLogger {
    static balance(balance) {
    console.log('Balance: £' + balance);
  }

  static notAllowedToWithdraw() {
    console.log('Not allowed to withdraw more than current balance.');
  }

  static latestTransation(transactionAmount) {
    console.log('Latest transaction amount is: £' + transactionAmount);
  }
}

/**
* Operations on accounts performed here
*/ 
class BankOperations {
  performActionWithBalance(action, balance, amountToActWith) {
    switch(action) {
        case BankOperationActions.WITHDRAW: {
        return balance - amountToActWith;
      }

      case BankOperationActions.DEPOSIT: {
        return balance + amountToActWith;
      }
    }
  }
}

const BankOperationActions = {
    WITHDRAW: 'withdraw',
    DEPOSIT: 'deposit'
}

/**
* Rules engine here for withdrawls
*/
class WithdrawlRules {
    /**
  * Can withdraw from the account test?
  * Add more rules here if required
  */
    static canWithdraw(requested, available) {
    if (WithdrawlRules.requestedAmountLessThanTotalAvailable(requested, available)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  static requestedAmountLessThanTotalAvailable(requested, available) {
    return requested <= available;
  }
}
```

Writing code like this makes unit testing possible, allowing you to be more confident in the code you are writing.

Then running like:

```
let bank = new BankCustomerClient(100, new ClientLogger());
bank.statement();
bank.deposit(10);
bank.statement();
bank.withdraw(10);
bank.statement();
bank.withdraw(1000);
bank.statement();
```

Logs:

```
"Balance: £100"
"Latest transaction amount is: £"
"Balance: £110"
"Balance: £110"
"Latest transaction amount is: £+10"
"Balance: £100"
"Balance: £100"
"Latest transaction amount is: £-10"
"Not allowed to withdraw more than current balance."
"Balance: £100"
"Latest transaction amount is: £-10"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help !